# Difference in usage between "мол" and "де"

Tags: выбор-слова

> Натолкнувшийся на меня Фарсад, невесело улыбнулся – **мол**, не у одного тебя кошки на душе скребут, потом вдруг со всего размаха врезал меня по плечу, и проговорил:

As particles to mark reported speech, how do they differ in usage?

As to "мол", does only context -- regardless of punctuation -- help determine which part of a sentence is such reported speech?

> Натолкнувшийся на меня Фарсад, невесело улыбнулся – мол, **не у одного тебя кошки на душе скребут**, потом вдруг со всего размаха врезал меня по плечу, и проговорил:

Comment: **мол** always precedes the reported speech, another one is **дЕскать**, enclitic **де** which is inserted into the reported speech is archaic and not used in modern language, admittedly the other two aren't exactly popular either

Answer (score 3):

**-де** is added to a word as a postfix, while **мол,** can precede a whole phrase or be inserted between words. The phrase should express reported speech or an allusion to someone else's words.

As **-де** tends to be an archaism now, it is stylistically demanding, and can sometimes be used to make the sentence a bit offencive. But a hundred years ago it was not offencive.

Comment: I think "confrontational" would describe it better than "offensive".

Comment: maybe rather skeptical and distrustful, but in fact all these words have undertone of skepticism and distrust in varying degree